# Keychain access on iOS

Tags: ios, keychain

having problems accessing keychain on iOS - code works fine with Mac. Whatever I do, I just get an error -50 returned (errSecParam). Any thoughts much appreciated. thx

```
    CFMutableDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreateMutable( nullptr, 10, nullptr, nullptr );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecClass, kSecClassGenericPassword );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrService, CFSTR( "test" ) );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrAccount, CFSTR( "test" ) );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecUseAuthenticationUI, kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip );
    CFDictionaryAddValue( query, kSecAttrAccessControl, kSecAttrAccessible );

    const auto res = SecItemAdd( query, nullptr );
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- the key value pair `kSecUseAuthenticationUI`, [`kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecuseauthenticationuiskip?language=objc) can only be used as an option to `SecCopyItemMatching`
- the value: [`kSecAttrAccessible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessible?language=objc) is a dictionary key not a value. The value for [`kSecAttrAccessControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccesscontrol?language=objc) should be a `SecAccessControlRef`.

If you remove both of these options it will work. Of course, you'll probably want to research what replacement values are needed to restore your original intent.

This information comes from the comments in the header files. I'll add links to the online docs if I can find them.

Updated with online links.